# draggable mask android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am looking for a tutorial to achieve an effect that is very easy to create with actionscript, but need to do it in `JAVA` for android.

Basically i want two images on top of each other, one with a draggable mask layer over top of it..  basically something like this even:

http://flashexplained.com/actionscript/how-to-easily-make-a-draggable-mask-with-actionscript/

Comment: i have upvoted people's responses.. but thanks for the "help"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have a `RelativeLayout` this way:

```
  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="true"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/top_mask"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignTop="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and code to access above mask and set its drag event this way:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.top_mask);
                img.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        params.topMargin = (int) event.getX();
                        params.bottomMargin = (int) event.getY();
                        v.setLayoutParams(params);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

I haven't tested this code. I just wrote this. I believe this must help you to get started or even a complete solution :)

regards,
Aqif Hamid